# wilcard searching in powershell

Tags: file, powershell, search

I work for a large organization that has many windows 2012 file servers where we re-direct AD users profile folders to.

Ever since Crypo-wall viruII have been plaguing us  we run search looking for the various telltale signatures that someone's account is infected.

The last campaign left files with a HELP_YOUR_FILES* in there so was easy to look for using

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*$fileName*") } | Select-Object Name,Directory| Format-Table -AutoSize *
```

Now starting this week we've been hit with a new Cryto-wall campaing that leaves affected user files like this

```
<original_filename>.extension.mp3
```

only using a search parameter of *.mp3 or even *.*.mp3 (in an attempt to catch the double barrel file extensions just keeps returning all mp3 files which is too large a list to sort through and find any infection.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to find only

```
<original_filename>.extension.mp3
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: sorry for some reason my filename example was not posted correctly. if should have been          original_filename.extension.mp3

Comment: Is it explicitly "extension.mp3" or is it the file's previous extension with .mp3 added to the end like ".txt.mp3" and ".xlsx.mp3"?

Comment: you are correct, the original file name with added.mp3

Comment: Did you try a search parameter of `*.*.mp3`? This finds `test.something.mp3`, but not `test.mp3` or `something.mp3`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RegEx match to help with this. It would not be perfect, but it would limit the results quite a bit. I think I would do something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -match "\.[^\.]+\.mp3$") } | Select-Object Name,Directory| Format-Table -AutoSize *
```

That will search for a pattern where there's a period, at least one non-period character, another period, and then mp3 with nothing after it. Here's a [RegEx101 Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/eR6iD9/2).

As the RegEx101 example shows in the last line matches, this is not fool proof, and would require manual review, but it should reduce false positive results to a minimum.

Comment: Great suggestion, I'll give it a try, given that some of our file servers are 2-5  TB in size reducing false positives would be a great thing, users do love to store mp3 files ! I'll let you know how this goes. Thanks again